# Copying a site to a multi-site installation

Tags: 7, multi-sites

On Server A (debian) drupal was installed by the package manager. So basically the codebase is at: `/usr/share/drupal7` with `/usr/share/drupal7/sites` symlinking to `/etc/drupal/7/sites`.

Server B has basically the same setup (ubuntu).

The multi-site feature is configured like that: At `/etc/drupal/7` we have a apache.conf:

```
Alias /site1 /usr/share/drupal7
Alias /site2 /usr/share/drupal7

<Directory /usr/share/drupal7/>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

I copied the Site from A to B. In A it was installed at /sites/default so I copied it to /sites/default at B. The index page (www.foo.com/drupal7) is redirected to /sites/default. So basically it works.

But if I go to e.g. www.foo.com/drupal7/members I get:
404: The requested URL /usr/share/drupal7/index.php was not found on this server.

Also: If I want a multisite like www.foo.com/site1 I create it at /sites/foo.com.site1

Question 1: How can I confiure it so it works on / rather than on /drupal7? So basically I'd like to use this site "normal" on /sites/default but another site at /sites/site1.

Question 2: How can I fix the 404 error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I confiure it so it works on / rather than on /drupal7

This has to do with your Apache `VirtualHost`. It probably is pointing to `/usr/share/` instead of to `/usr/share/drupal7`. So in order to access the content in the `drupal7` folder, you need to add the folder to the url.

> Question 2: How can I fix the 404 error?

Relating to:

> But if I go to e.g. www.foo.com/drupal7/members I get: 404: The requested URL /usr/share/drupal7/index.php was not found on this server.

The first thing is figuring out if there is an `index.php` file there. If so, does it have the correct permissions?

It seems to be an Apache error, not a Drupal error at this point. ;)

Comment: yeah from what I see there isn't really any vhost config except the apache.conf I posted above.  And they all point to /usr/share/drupal7. But it's possible that I'll have to write proper rewrite ruels since alias might not work in this case. Or just set up proper vhost.

Comment: also, I just saw that a htaccess file points 404 errors to /index..php which might explain my error from above. So basically it can't resolve /members because I only use aliases (i guess) and then trhows a 404 and then I get the strange index error.

Comment: The 404 could be an issue with the rewrite rules and clean urls. Could you try accessing it via `/index.php?q=members` instead of `/members`. The 404 error, is it on an error page themed like your site?

Comment: thanks you! You reminded me of looking at the rewrite rules - which were wrong configured. Everything works fine now. :) Thanks everyone.